# Optimizing Apache2 for high volume of small requests

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, centos6, httpd, perl

I have a Perl script which returns a string, it's very simple and small.
It is running on `CentOS 6.4` with `mod-prefork` and `mod_cgi` via `httpd 2.2.15` over `SSL`.
It is the directory index, so when you visit the site, the script is run and that's all. The requests will be POST and some XML data will be sent by the clients to the server.

I expect tens of thousands of hits repeatedly. What can I do to prepare?

Answer (score 3):

- Hit your site with tens of thousands of requests and see how it and the underlying infrastructure perform.
- Increase the number of hits and monitor what happens.
- Rinse and repeat.

Comment: +1. THere are even TOOLS to do that. Test it. FInished.

Comment: That helps to get metrics, I was hoping for an answer more along the line of "proxy SSL terminations to nginx because it is faster", "use mod-worker because X", "use a reverse proxy because Y".  But I'll settle for this :)  Thanks.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal: Any or all of those may be solutions to problems that you encounter but without having baseline statistics and measurements how would you (or anyone) know? Also remember we know nothing at all about your app or how it performs so how can we advise?

Answer (score 0):

what @Iain said + you might want to perftest [**lighttpd**](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/docs_modcgi) or [**yaws**](http://hyber.org/) against apache-performance, especially server-values like load, ram, iowait etc

apache is good, apache is fast, but has its problems when speaking of massive parallel requests.